# Magento 2 custom newsletter form

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, newsletter

I took the solution from here: [Magento 2.2 - adding name field to newsletter module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201216/magento-2-2-adding-name-field-to-newsletter-module/201242#201242)

It is working fine on a CMS page but it is interrupting work of the standard subscribe form.

```
Exception message: Notice: Undefined variable: result
```

We have it in the footer of the website and it is not working now. Any advice on that

Comment: it will help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201216/magento-2-2-adding-name-field-to-newsletter-module?noredirect=1&lq=1