# Magento 2 : create newsletter subscription CMS page

Tags: magento2, cms, newsletter, transactional-mail, newsletter-block

do you have any reference that can share, how to create a CMS page that has a newsletter subscription form in it? I don't need an extra column for the data. Once the user subscribes there, it will automatically create a record at the newsletter subscription page, and also send a confirmation email to the subscriber, just like filling out the newsletter subscription box at all the pages.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create new **CMS page** from

> Admin->Content->Pages->Add New Page

```
Page Title = Newsletter /*As you want*/
Content Heading = Subscribe to our Newsletter /*As you want*/
```

Then add the below content in Body

```
{{block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="static.newsletter" template="Magento_Newsletter::subscribe.phtml"}}
```

It will create a page with a Newsletter subscription form and save the data.

Check the below screenshots.

**CMS page.**

[image]

**Saved Data.**

[image]

Comment: Thanks,  what about customer first name and last name? Possible to create custom block for it?

Comment: You have to create a module to save the additional fields for the guest subscriber, Check this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/201242/59677 or registered customer automatically saves the first name and last name, Also please accept the answer if my answer is worked for you.

Comment: I did check this solution out too, but I have no idea why need to install Schema, I saw the Customer Firstname and Lastname field should there already.

Comment: I found out subscriber table has no field contain firstname and lastname, firstname and lastname is base on the customer_id, if customer_id is 0, then they are the guest.

Comment: Is my answer worked for you?