# Magento 2 + How to add first name and country field in newsletter subscription form?

Tags: magento2, module, newsletter, newsletter-subscriber

I have **Magento 2.3.4** I want to show the "first name" and "country" field in the **newsletter subscription** **form**. Also, it would be for guests and customers as well. Both fields should be shown in the admin grid and that will be sent in emails as well.

**How can I achieve this functionality?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take help from here.

[Magento 2.2 - adding name field to newsletter module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201216/magento-2-2-adding-name-field-to-newsletter-module/201242)

In this solution they are adding FirstName and LastName to newsletter form, you should replace them with "First Name" and "country" fields at every occurrence.

Comment: I tried this and added country instead of the last name but in my project, there is a subscribe.phtml is already loading from diff place, from theme "app/design/frontend/theme/name/Magento_Newsletter/subscribe-footer.phtml"
it does not override out phtml file. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you run the commands php bin/magento setup:di:compile && php bin/magento cache:flush ?

Comment: also check by adding code of app\code\Hm\Newsletters\view\frontend\templates - subscribe.phtml

into 
"app/design/frontend/theme/name/Magento_Newsletter/subscribe-footer.phtml" if it works, take a backup of files first.