# Magento 2 : save additional attributes in newsletter

Tags: magento2, newsletter, newsletter-subscriber

I have a promotional popup on home page, asking to subscribe a newsletter.
Also I want to save gender and Interested Categories of that User. 
How I can save these additional Information to 'newsletter_subscriber' table.

I have referred this link: 
[Magento 2 : How to add additional fields to newsletter](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146952/magento-2-how-to-add-additional-fields-to-newsletter)

So Fields are added to table and admin grid, but it doesn't save gender and category data to table.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

please check SS.
[image]

[image]

Adding Some code here,

```
   public function aroundSubscribe($subject, \Closure $proceed, $email) {
    $result = $proceed($email);
    if ($this->request->isPost() && $this->request->getPost('gender')) {
        print_r($this->request->getPost('gender'));
        exit;
        $gender = $this->request->getPost('gender');
        $category = $this->request->getPost('category');

        $subject->setGender($gender);
        $subject->setInterestedCategory($category);


        try {
            $subject->save();
        }catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: any Exception ???

Comment: Can you please add entire code of you file? Are you getting values when you try to print "gender"?

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal no it doesn't give any exception or error. this is the main logic to save via plugin. let me know which code you want to check?

Comment: try to print your values in debug log and see what you are getting in debug.log file.

Comment: ok.. will check and let you know

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal this is log file..
2020-01-08T05:11:37+00:00 INFO (6): save news letterZend\Stdlib\Parameters Object
(
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
        (
            [email] => panchaldimple8@gmail.com
            [gender] => 2
            [category] => 43
            [form_key] => owLQ4GJEb4e2MMRn
        )

)

Comment: Can you please add all the files which you have created using the link you mentioned in your question?

Comment: so right now are you storing values?

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel No, it doesnt save values. all values are coming right.
$logger->info('isPost-'.print_r($this->request->isPost(),true));
        $logger->info('gender'.print_r($this->request->getPost('gender'),true));

        //$result = $proceed($email);
        if ($this->request->getPost()) {

            $logger->info('in if condition',true);
            die();
its not printing 'in if condition'

Comment: ok so when you post then that time no post values comes , am I right?

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal I am using popup to subscibe and to save values using same url as 'magento/newsletter/subscriber/new/'

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel no values are coming, but que is that why its not going in if condition while values are proper.

Comment: yes condition is ok

Comment: but we need to debug step by steps.

Comment: can you share that code, you want to use form?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103013/discussion-between-sarvesh-dineshkumar-patel-and-dimple-panchal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I found the answer to add additional data to news letter.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber">
    <plugin name="vendor_module_newsletter_model_subscriber" type="vendor\module\Plugin\Newsletter\Subscriber" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

and a plugin file

```
public function aroundSubscribe(\Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber $subject, \Closure $proceed, $email) {

    if ($this->request->isPost() && $this->request->getPost('gender')) {
        $gender = $this->request->getPost('gender');
        $category = $this->request->getPost('category');

        $subject->setGender($gender);
        $subject->setInterestedCategory($category);

        $result = $proceed($email);

        try {
            $subject->save();

        }catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

mistake was $result = $proceed($email); line has to write after saving additional data.

hope will work !!

Comment: You should write $result = $proceed($email); line code outside if condition. If condition will not true then, it will stop execution and return error. Not sure. But, as i know it will create issue.