# Magento 2: How can I add new field and save data to newsletter database table?

Tags: magento2, database, event-observer, plugin

How can I save data in a new field in newsletter table of database? This is how I created my module based on other answers, but no one of aproaches worked. The fields of column `c_firstname` is always NULL. Magento version 2.4.3.
This was what I have tried based on the following answers:

[how i can save the data from custom newsletter to database](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/344887/how-i-can-save-the-data-from-custom-newsletter-to-database#comment484851_344887)

[Magento 2 : save additional attributes in newsletter](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/300563/magento-2-save-additional-attributes-in-newsletter)

[Magento 2 : How to add additional fields to newsletter](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146952/magento-2-how-to-add-additional-fields-to-newsletter)

Please, someone could help me?

Thanks in advance!

**Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <type name="Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber">
    <plugin name="vendor_newsletters_newsletter_model_subscriber" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Subscriber" sortOrder="1" />
  </type>
</config>
```

**Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="newsletter_subscriber_save_before">
        <observer name="newsletter_subscriber_save_before" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\newsletterSubscriberSave" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Newsletter" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Vendor/Observer/newsletterSubscriberSave.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class newsletterSubscriberSave implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->_request = $request;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $subscriber = $observer->getEvent()->getSubscriber();
        $params = $this->_request->getParams();

        if(isset($params['c_firstname'])) {
            $name = $params['c_firstname'];
            $subscriber->setSubscriberName($name);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Vendor/Module/Plugin/Model/Subscriber.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model;

use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;

class Subscriber {
    protected $request;
    
    public function __construct(Http $request){
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function aroundSubscribe(\Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber $subject, \Closure $proceed, $email) {

        if ($this->request->isPost() && $this->request->getPost('c_firstname')) { 
            
            $firstname = $this->request->getPost('c_firstname');
            /* $lastname = $this->request->getPost('lastname'); */

            $subject->setCFirstname($firstname);
            /* $subject->setCLastname($lastname); */
            $result = $proceed($email);
            
            try {
                $subject->save();
            }catch (\Exception $e) {
                throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

**Vendor/Module/etc/db_schema.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="newsletter_subscriber" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Newsletter Subscriber">
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="c_firstname" nullable="false" comment="First Name"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="c_lastname" nullable="false" comment="Last Name"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

**Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/newsletter_subscriber_block.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.newsletter.subscriber.container">
            <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Adminhtml\Subscriber\Grid" name="adminhtml.newslettrer.subscriber.grid" as="grid">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">subscriberGrid</argument>
                    <argument name="dataSource" xsi:type="object">Magento\Newsletter\Model\ResourceModel\Subscriber\Grid\Collection</argument>
                    <argument name="default_sort" xsi:type="string">subscriber_id</argument>
                    <argument name="default_dir" xsi:type="string">desc</argument>
                    <argument name="use_ajax" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Massaction" name="adminhtml.newslettrer.subscriber.grid.massaction" as="grid.massaction">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="massaction_id_field" xsi:type="string">subscriber_id</argument>
                        <argument name="form_field_name" xsi:type="string">subscriber</argument>
                        <argument name="use_select_all" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                        <argument name="options" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="unsubscribe" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Unsubscribe</item>
                                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/massUnsubscribe</item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="delete" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/massDelete</item>
                            </item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Export" name="adminhtml.newslettrer.subscriber.grid.export" as="grid.export">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="exportTypes" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="csv" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="urlPath" xsi:type="string">*/*/exportCsv</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CSV</item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="excel" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="urlPath" xsi:type="string">*/*/exportXml</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Excel XML</item>
                            </item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\ColumnSet" name="adminhtml.newslettrer.subscriber.grid.columnSet" as="grid.columnSet">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">problemGrid</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="subscriber_id">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">subscriber_id</argument>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="email">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">subscriber_email</argument>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-email</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">ccol-email</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="type">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Type</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">type</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
                            <argument name="options" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="guest" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Guest</item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="customer" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer</item>
                                </item>
                            </argument>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-type</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-type</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="firstname">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer First Name</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">firstname</argument>
                            <argument name="renderer" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Block\Newsletter\Adminhtml\Template\Grid\Renderer\Customerfirstname</argument>
                            <argument name="default" xsi:type="string">----</argument>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-first-name</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-first-name</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="lastname">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Last Name</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">lastname</argument>
                            <argument name="renderer" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Block\Newsletter\Adminhtml\Template\Grid\Renderer\Customerlastname</argument>
                            <argument name="default" xsi:type="string">----</argument>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-last-name</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-last-name</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="status">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">subscriber_status</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
                            <argument name="options" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="status_not_active" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Not Activated</item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="status_subscribed" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Subscribed</item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="status_unsubscribed" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">3</item>
                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Unsubscribed</item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="status_unconfirmed" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">4</item>
                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Unconfirmed</item>
                                </item>
                            </argument>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-status</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-status</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Multistore" as="website">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Web Site</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">website_id</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
                            <argument name="options" xsi:type="options" model="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Website\OptionHash"/>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-website</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-website</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Multistore" as="group">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">group_id</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
                            <argument name="options" xsi:type="options" model="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe\Grid\Options\GroupOptionHash"/>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-store</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-store</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Multistore" as="store">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store View</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">store_id</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
                            <argument name="options" xsi:type="options" model="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe\Grid\Options\StoreOptionHash"/>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-store-view</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-store-view</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.components">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="newsletter_head_components" template="Magento_Newsletter::js/components.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        
        <referenceContainer name="page.bottom.container">
            <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="form.subscribe.new" before="-" template="Vendor_Module::subscribe.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="form.subscribe" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

**Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/subscribe.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var \Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe $block */

?>
<div class="newsletter">
    <div class="content">
        <form class="form subscribe container" novalidate
              action="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getFormActionUrl()) ?>"
              method="post"
              data-mage-init='{"validation": {"errorClass": "mage-error"}}'
              id="newsletter-validate-detail">
              <div class="right">
                <div class="inputs">
                    <div class="field firstname">                
                        <div class="control">
                            <input name="c_firstname" type="text" id="c_firstname" placeholder="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Type your first name')) ?>" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- <div class="field lastname">
                        <label class="label" for="lastname"><span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Last Name')) ?></span></label>
                        <div class="control">
                            <input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" placeholder="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Type your last name')) ?>" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                        </div>
                    </div> -->
                    <div class="field newsletters">                
                        <div class="control">
                            <input name="email" type="email" id="newsletter" placeholder="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Type you email')) ?>" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="actions">
                        <button class="action subscribe primary button -black" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Win your discount!')) ?>" type="submit">
                            <span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Win your discount!')) ?></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Vendor/Module/registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are using outdated logic

In Magento 2.4.3 uses another way to subscribe. See `\Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriptionManagerInterface`.

You can implement you own logic for this interface and define `preference`

```xml
<preference for="Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriptionManagerInterface"
    type="Acme\StackExchange\Model\SubscriptionManager"/>
```

or create plugin for `\Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriptionManager`

Also you can see subscribe logic in  `\Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction::execute`